# Global.asax file is missing on my Asp.Net Empty Web application project

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I have created a C#-> Asp.Net Empty Web Application (Framework 4.0). I want to add few line of code in Global.asax on Application_Error section. But unfortuantely global.asax file is missing. How can i add that file? My visual studio version is 2012

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can add a new file to the project of type **Global Application Class**

```
File -> New -> File -> Global Application Class
```

Alternately, you can create a new temporary project, which should generate a Global.asax file. Then just copy/paste that into your project.

Comment: I just followed File -> New -> File -> Global Application Class and it created Global1.asax file then i have choosed "Moved Global1.asax to my project" option in file menu. But still i am not getting glboal1.asax.cs file?

Comment: @Selva did you already have a Global.asax file? Your question is worded in such a way that it seems that's what you need. Or do you just need the .cs file?

Comment: Hmmmm! The Global.asax seems to be already on your project.  I would close Visual Studio and reopen it.  When adding Global.asax, it should shows at Global.asax, not Global1.asax.

Comment: I noticed in VS2015 that you will not see the Global Application Class option if you already have a global.asax when choosing 'Add New Item > C# > Web'. I had the aspx w/o the .cs. I had to first delete the aspx, then re-add to get the .cs

Answer (score 11):

You can also add it from project i.e. right click the project and add new item there you can find or search for Global Application Class template and add it.It's done.

Comment: This Worked For me

Comment: As user @puddleglum mentions in another comment, the template is only displayed if there is not already a Global.asax file. If you don't see the template you do  in fact have a Global.asax, but you have overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

Goto File->New->Project->web->Asp.Net Web Application->select Web form-click Ok.
Now you are done; you see the Global Application file when you select web forms while creating a new project. Try this and let me know.