# Application_Start() & Application_End() methods are not fired in startup.cs class in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, startup, global-asax

There is no **Global.aspx.cs** class in ASP.NET MVC 5 application where I can have the methods `Application_Start()` and  `Application_End()`. 
Is there any way to invoke these methods in MVC 5 application?

Comment: Because startup.cs class do not call these methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application\_Start not firing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641148/application-start-not-firing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually add `Global.asax` to your project as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535924/global-asax-file-is-missing-on-my-asp-net-empty-web-application-project).

Otherwise, you can use `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` or constructor in your `Startup.cs`. `Configuration` is called "slightly later" than `Application_Start` as mentioned in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168978/do-i-need-a-global-asax-cs-file-at-all-if-im-using-an-owin-startup-cs-class-and).

Comment: I've added and I am getting a Parser Error while running the application

Comment: What's your parser error message? Show it as edit in your question. NB: The Global.asax file should have same namespace as project's namespace.