# Can't find global application class nor Global. asax file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to add an API service to my existing .NET web application.

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzJm0lPIoJY) tutorial, but couldn't found any option to add web service.

Then I followed these two questions on Stackoverflow ([Where is the Global.asax.cs file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288209/where-is-the-global-asax-cs-file) and [Global.asax file is missing on my Asp.Net Empty Web application project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535924/global-asax-file-is-missing-on-my-asp-net-empty-web-application-project)) but couldn't find the Add option for the global application class. How can I resolve this issue? Am I doing something wrong?

I tried to create a new solution, the problem is the same.

- I'm using VisualStudio 2019 16.4.6
- My project's targeted framework is .NET Core 3.1

If there is any tutorial or written document for adding web API to an existing project please give me, that would be very helpful. I tried to follow [this](http://andreyzavadskiy.com/2018/03/31/adding-web-api-controller-to-existing-mvc-project/) blog and installed *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core* and got this warning -

> Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

[image]

Comment: Your existing web API project targets to which .net framework?

Comment: I don't have any existing web api projects. I want to add a new api service to may existing web application project (website) which is targeted for .NET Core 3.1

Comment: If you are following a tutorial, follow its every steps. Right now you created a .NET Core project which does not match the .NET Framework project used in that tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

With ASP.NET Core, the entry point to an application is `Startup`, and you no longer have a dependency on `Global.asax`.

You can find more about it on [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#globalasax-file-replacement)

To consume an API you can use RestSharp in your Asp.net Core Application.
You can check [this link](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3489481/how-to-consume-an-aspnet-core-web-api-using-restsharp.html) to learn more about consuming an API using RestSharp in your Asp.net Core Application.

Answer (score 1):

> My project's targeted framework is .NET Core 3.1

Global.asax.cs will not be generated if you use ASP.NET Core. You have to use older version of ASP.NET, for example ASP.NET 4 (4.7.2) if you want to follow that old tutorial.

Or you can try a tutorial for WebApi using Asp.Net Core like this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio